# REST API testing using Selenium webdriver+Maven+TestNg

Tags: rest, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Has any one tested REST API's using selenium webdriver+Maven+TestNG. Please share the information or sample project

Comment: Why do you think you need WebDriver for this? (You don't)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium WebDriver is for interacting with web browsers, not HTTP APIs (RESTful or otherwise).

There are lots of HTTP client libraries available that work well with Maven and TestNG. Here are some:

- [HTTP Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/) by Google
- [Jersey Client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html) & [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html) by Oracle
- [Spring RestTemplate](http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/) by Pivotal Software
- [Apache CXF Client API](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html) by The Apache Software Foundation

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the mfulton26 answer,

You can also use [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) (which is open source) to test REST APT. Check [this link](http://www.testautomationguru.com/how-to-test-rest-api-using-jmeter/) for more details.

JMeter plugins are available for

- [ANT](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part1/)
- [Maven](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin)
- [Gradle](https://github.com/jmeter-gradle-plugin/jmeter-gradle-plugin)
- [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin)

Comment: Seriously?? Can the downvoter explain what is wrong here?

Comment: JMeter is performance testing tool. You can use it for functional testing but it's better to consider the tools that are design to do it.

Comment: @IgorKhrol, the answer is very clear that along with the accepted answer, I provide an additional info. also, JMeter has nice GUI, you do not have to write any code to do a basic REST API testing. Many people use JMeter for functional validation. So that the same script can be used for performance validation as well.